# Create new list variable with "ifelse" and logical operator ||

Tags: r, list, logical-operators

I'm creating a new list variable by the following rationale:

```
new.list <- lapply(old.list, function(x) {
x$`list$new.variable` <- ifelse(x$`list$condition` == 2, x$`list$reactiontime`, NA) x})
```

I'm telling R that my new list variable (`new.variable`) needs to contain the reaction time value (`list$reactiontime`) based only on condition 2 (defined through `list$condition`). If condition is not 2, then add NA in new variable.

This works fine...

If I use the logical operator for or (`|`) in order to select values based on two conditions, it doesn't work anymore and just copies the whole reactiontime variable instead of the specific values.

```
new.list <- lapply(old.list, function(x) {
x$`list$new.variable` <- ifelse(x$`list$condition` == 2 **| 6**, x$`list$reactiontime`, NA)
    x})
```

How can I use logical operators to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the or operator `|` as follows:

```
x <- 1:4
ifelse(x == 1 | x == 3, 2, NA)
# [1]  2 NA  2 NA
```

That is, you also have to add the full condition after the `|` and not only the value.